# PIE not working in ie 8 but 7, 9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, css3pie, gradient

Hi for some reason pie isnt working on my rounded corners, can anybody please help. Below is my CSS, in ie8 it doesnt show the background color either just the text within the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/doddsy1005/VcrGL/1/

may be due to a filter like this.`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4265b', endColorstr='#e10e49',GradientType=0 );`

Answer (score 0):

As per your remark in the question: yes, it may very well be due to the `filter`.

There is a well-known bug with gradients drawn using `filter` that messes up rounded corners. This bug is best known in IE9, because IE9 does support `border-radius`, but still needs `filter` gradients, so they often clash. I can easily see that it might break CSS3Pie's rounded corners as well though.

I guess the real question is why are you using `filter` at all for gradients? If you're using CSS3Pie for rounded corners, you can also use it for CSS gradients; it supports both features. The whole point of CSS3Pie is that you don't have to do things like use `filter` for gradients.

So the answer is simply to stop using `filter` for your gradients. Use CSS3Pie as you already do for `border-radius`, and the problem will go away.

Hope that helps.